# Adding single quotes to a cell using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, single-quotes

I am trying to add single quotes to values in a column by using `Chr(39)`, but I am only getting the second quote.
e.g. I want **'value'** but I am getting **value'**

But if I use double quotes by using `Chr(34)` it works, and I get **"value"**

```
Sub AddQuote()
Dim myCell As Range
    For Each myCell In Selection
        If myCell.Value <> "" Then
            myCell.Value = Chr(39) & myCell.Value & Chr(39)
        End If
    Next myCell
End Sub
```

Comment: so close! - I'll add my solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just add another single quote:

```
Sub AddQuote()
Dim myCell As Range
    For Each myCell In Selection
        If myCell.Value <> "" Then
            myCell.Value = Chr(39) & Chr(39) & myCell.Value & Chr(39)
        End If
    Next myCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer this syntax. Instead of looping through each cell, just read the whole selection into an array, act on the array, then dump the array contents back onto the worksheet. A maximum of two touches of the worksheet.

```
Sub AddQuote()

  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  Dim inputData As Variant
  Dim outputData As Variant

  ' only act on a range
  If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
    ' assign selection value to a Variant array
    inputData = Selection.Value
    ' create an output array of the same size
    ReDim outputData(LBound(inputData) To UBound(inputData), _
                     LBound(inputData, 2) To UBound(inputData, 2))

    ' loop through all array dimensions
    For i = LBound(inputData) To UBound(inputData)
      For j = LBound(inputData, 2) To UBound(inputData, 2)
        ' array element will be = Empty if cell was empty
        If Not IsEmpty(inputData(i, j)) Then
          outputData(i, j) = Chr(39) & Chr(39) & inputData(i, j) & Chr(39)
        End If
      Next j
    Next i

    Selection.Value = outputData
  End If

End Sub
```

It also accounts for a multiple-column selection.

Answer (score 2):

The first quote ' means the cell is treated as text.

So you'll have to use two single quotes on the LHS, and one on the right for it to appear correctly.

note if **A1** = `''test'` and **A2** = `''abc'`

Then `=A1&A2` will give you `'test''abc'` as you'd expect

Comment: +1 for suggesting the correct method, although you might consider adding sample code for the OP to use/adapt.